# How can I zoom in when a participant shares their screen on BlueJeans web app?

Tags: bluejeans

How can I zoom in when a participant shares their screen on BlueJeans web app?

On the BlueJeans desktop program one can double click but that doesn't seem to work with the BlueJeans web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the BlueJeans tech support, one currently cannot zoom in when a participant shares their screen on BlueJeans web app.